# Any risks in installing my own http server?

Tags: apache, webserver, xampp

To save bandwidth and play around using PHP and all without any limits, I was thinking of installing my own web server.

However, I was wondering if there any risks:

- Is my computer more exposed to security risks? If I set up my router *not* to forward any incoming requests to my computer, will it really have no security risks?
- Is it a wise solution to install XAMPP, so as not to clutter around with installing each separate server and stuff?
- Can I uninstall XAMPP and all its siblings whenever I'd like to? Will an uninstall make my computer clean of the install again, or will there be alot of traces left?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should belong on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Oh sorry, actually I looked at the faq here stating "software tools commonly used by programmers", so I thought I was right... Can I move it or should I post it on Server Fault for a second time?

Comment: @pimvdb To be honest, you'll most likely get a better response on that site as it's specifically targeted as such topics. However, there's no need to take any action - this question will be automatically migrated if sufficient people believe this to be the case.

Comment: XAMPP is pretty easy to uninstall. I believe it also works in a VM for added security. Provided you're behind a firewall, you should be fine.

Comment: Actually, the faq at Server Fault says that no questions should be asked there about "running servers at home for personal use". Anyway, I'll just leave it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry at all about installing Apache on a local machine if you're not going to be forwarding traffic to it. If traffic can't get to it, the only possible security issues would be from things internal to your network, and if you're at home that's just you anyway. It's a great way to get familiar with it.

I'm on linux, but XAMPP sounds like a very convenient way to go about it.

Comment: I saw XAMPP installs way too much supplements, so I decided to use EasyPHP. There was a Wikipedia page about it, so I'm fine concerning security I guess. Thanks