# Risks by creating a Minetest in one's own network - Raspberry Pi 3 - Raspbian

Tags: networking, server, raspbian

I want to create a Minetest server on my Raspberry Pi 3 in my own network.
I know some discussions have been made (like [Any risks in installing my own http server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820089/any-risks-in-installing-my-own-http-server)), but I want to create a Minetest server.
I would like to know
  • If it's dangerous to create a server in my own network
  • If I can make a protection if it's dangerous.

Thanks

PS : Sorry for the mistakes, I'm French!

Comment: How secure is your network?  Is it a public network?  Ethernet requiring physical access?  Is physical access an indication of trust ( being in your house vs shared house or academic setting )?  Or is it wireless?  How good is the wireless security?  There's less physical access requirement for wireless.   Finally, how well can you enumerate the valid hosts?

Comment: It's a private network (in my house). The Raspberry Pi is connected using Ethernet (maybe I will use Wi-Fi sometimes). The network use WPA-Personal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume here that you're intending to serve this internally.  You certainly wouldn't want to put an external game server on a network that was also shared by your household.  The Raspberry PI is assumed to be internal itself without a public IP or any way to be addressed beyond the local network.

Realistically speaking, you can probably assume an internal network is safe enough for inconsequential internal services, if physical and wireless access is adequately controlled.  Looks like minetest is a game server, so unless you combine its server with other far more sensitive tasks, it's not like there's any dire consequence to unauthorized access.

But that perspective does seem a little naive, doesn't it?  If access *were* to occur, the raspberry pi could probably be compromised, and from there, the IoT devices in the home, other private services, etc are at risk too.  So, perhaps you're just a little too paranoid / experienced / virtuous to leave it at that.

If so, we can probably assume that the connection itself doesn't support much in the way of encryption, but it's likely we can successfully tunnel the connection in any number of ways to add an encryption layer "between" client and server.

The simplest of these is probably ssh. You're already using it to manage your raspberry pi, probably, and if you're not, you might want to (I for one need copy/paste between web and terminal, and I don't want to run gui on pi!).  SSH offers a much higher standard of security than most protocols.

Conceptually, you execute an ssh client locally on the game client configured to open a local port on the game client, and forwards packet recieved on that port to a remote port on the ssh server.  The remote port need not be accessible on the network directly, only ssh ( the game server would listen on localhost).  The ssh tunnel uses strong encryption methods to pass the traffic over the untrusted network ( yours, or perhaps any network for some traffic ).

The process when implemented, would look something like this:

1. actiate ssh server on pi if not yet done,
2. obtain ssh client for game client machine. ( Putty for old windows, built in for linux or osx etc, new windows might have better support).
3. generate ssh keypair on client (each client should do these steps.  private keys are ideally never transferred.  )
4. add public key to ssh user on pi  and verify that you can login without password
5. Use SSH tunnel in oyur client to create a local port that tunnels to the remote game server port.  https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-tunnel-with-putty/ looks like a good putty tutorial, https://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html looks decent for unixy environs.

I prefer to take the safe and lazy route, assuming no network is necessarily secure, and weighing the convenience of accessibility against the securiry concerns. Using an ssh tunnel is, once you get used to it, a simple and straightforward way to access services across any untrusted network, by it your own, a public wifi, or the internet at large.

Comment: Hum... Actually, I would have liked to create an extern server to play with my friends... Is it very dangerous or can I make it sure ? Thanks

Comment: You could always use ssh tunnels for all your friends too ... or you could whitelist their IPs ( that isn't as secure because traffic would probably be discoverable via man in the middle, since the game probably doesn't use TLS or anything to encrypt its traffic ).  You could put the server in a "DMZ" that doesn't route to the rest of your network.  Or you could set up a VPN like openvpn so that the traffic was encrypted.